# Static Array Declaration and Initialization

Tags: javascript

I am learning JS from scratch and implementing HighCharts code using JS. Seeing one of the demo I see a variable data array declaration like below:

```
        data = [{
        y: 55.11,
        color: colors[0],
        drilldown: {
           name: 'MSIE versions',
           categories: ['MSIE 8.0', 'MSIE 6.0', 'MSIE 7.0', 'MSIE 9.0'],
           data: [{
               y: 33.06,
               drilldown: {
                   name: 'drilldown next level',
                   categories: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
                   data: [23,54,47],
                   color: colors[0]
               }
           }, 10.85, 7.35, 2.41],
           color: colors[0]
        }
     }, {
         y: 21.63,
        color: colors[1],
        drilldown: {
           name: 'Firefox versions',
           categories: ['Firefox 3.6', 'Firefox 4.0', 'Firefox 3.5', 'Firefox 3.0', 'Firefox 2.0'],
           data: [13.52, 5.43, 1.58, 0.83, 0.20],
           color: colors[1]
        }
     }];
```

What does this 'data' array declaration means?

Comment: It's initilize an array of objects. what else can we way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an array with two elements, each one an object. Those are declared in [object literal notation](http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/obj_lit.php). For instance, the second element is this:

```
{
    y: 21.63,
    color: colors[1],
    drilldown: {
       name: 'Firefox versions',
       categories: ['Firefox 3.6', 'Firefox 4.0', 'Firefox 3.5', 'Firefox 3.0', 'Firefox 2.0'],
       data: [13.52, 5.43, 1.58, 0.83, 0.20],
       color: colors[1]
    }
 }
```

This object is composed of various properties. For instance, the property "y" has the value 21.63. The property "drilldown" is another object and so on. Primitives, arrays, and objects can be embedded ad infinitum.

Furthermore, I can deduct that data[ 0 ] and data[ 1 ] appear to be similar objects since they have the same properties.

One thing that may help if you're having a hard time seeing the structure is being very strict about your code style, especially indentation. I've reworked it a little bit and shown a very generous spacing. It takes up more lines, but it should be clearer what is related.

```
data = [
    {
        y: 55.11,
        color: colors[0],
        drilldown: {
        name: 'MSIE versions',
            categories: ['MSIE 8.0', 'MSIE 6.0', 'MSIE 7.0', 'MSIE 9.0'],
            data: [
                {
                    y: 33.06,
                    drilldown: {
                        name: 'drilldown next level',
                        categories: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
                        data: [23,54,47],
                        color: colors[0]
                    }
                },
                10.85,
                7.35,
                2.41
            ],
            color: colors[0]
        }
    },{
        y: 21.63,
        color: colors[1],
        drilldown: {
            name: 'Firefox versions',
            categories: ['Firefox 3.6', 'Firefox 4.0', 'Firefox 3.5', 'Firefox 3.0', 'Firefox 2.0'],
            data: [13.52, 5.43, 1.58, 0.83, 0.20],
            color: colors[1]
        }
    }
];
```

Comment: Thanks does that means I can access a member like data[0].drilldown.color for its value?

Comment: Yup. Absolutely! Try writing console.log(data) in Firebug or google chrome dev tools. It'll give you an explorable object which shows you  exactly what the structure is.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your confusion is with the `data` arrays that begin as `data = [{` rather than the static arrays like `data : [23,54,47]`,

`data` is an array containing several object literals, each of which has a property called `drilldown` containing another similar structure which may contain another such `data` array.

It can be broken down into a structure similar to this:

```
data --> (array)
          |--> object
          |       --> name
          |       --> category
          |       --> drilldown (object)
          |             --> data (array)
          |                 |--> object
          |                 |--> object
          |--> object
                 --> name
                 --> category
                 --> drilldown (object)
                      --> data (array)
                           |--> object
                           |--> object
```

Answer (score 0):

`data` is an array that contains two object literals.  Each object literal in turn contains various properties, some simple, like `y` and `color` and some more complex, like `drilldown`, which is itself an object literal with its own properties.

At times like these, it is good to have very clear formatting to make it easier to see what belongs to what.

Answer (score 0):

Data is an object and it contains some objects, every curly braces {} represents an object. For example

```
var data=[{
    a:'Hello',b:'world'},
    {
        x:'Hello World',
        y:function(){ alert(this.x);}
    }];
```

In above example

```
{a:'Hello',b:'world'} // This object contains two properties/variables a and b
```

is an object and it's the first (index 0) element of data array and

```
{
    x:'Hello World' // This is a property/Variable of 2nd objec
    y:function(){ alert(this.x);}, // This is a method/function of 2nd object

}
```

is the 2nd (index 1) element of data array and you can call

```
alert(data[0].a); // Will alert "hello" because first (0) item/object of data array has a variable that's value is "hello"
data[1].y(); // Will alert "Hello World" because 2nd item/object of data array has a method/function that alerts it's 'x' variable's data, 'this' indicates current object.
```

A fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sbbAU/).